# Retriving more than 100 results using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: simple-html-dom, information-retrieval

I used the following code to extract search results from "PHP Simple HTML DOM"

```
$url  = "http://www.google.com/search?      hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q={'$query'}&oq={'$query'}";

$html = file_get_html($url);
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a');
```

but it returned maximum 10 results is anyway to retrieve 100 results from the search?
Thank you

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem ? if yes, why don't you accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use num=100 parameter in the url like this one

```
$url  = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&num=100&q={'$query'}&oq={'$query'}";
```